# Inverted empirical CDF with averaging including BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: probability-or-statistics, charts

I'm new to Mathematica and started using it because of interest in statistics. So I've started reading books about statistics and found the problem, that the *inverted empirical CDF with averaging* method (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quantile.html) - as used in my books - was not supported by Mathematica including `BoxWhiskerChart`.

This was a great training for me to test my understanding and here is the result open for comments and improvements:

```
(* Define first the inverted empirical CDF with averaging function \
QUANTILEIECDAVE *)
ClearAll[myIF]
SetAttributes[myIF, HoldAll]
myIF[cond_, iftrue_, iffalse_] := 
  With[{result = 
     Replace[cond, {True :> iftrue, False :> iffalse, _ :> None}]}, 
   result /; result =!= None];
QUANTILEIECDAVE[x_, q_] := 
  Module[{s = Sort[x], n = Length[x]}, 
   myIF[IntegerQ[n*#], 1/2 (s[[n*#]] + s[[n*# + 1]]), 
      s[[Ceiling[n*#]]]] & /@ q];

(* For the BoxWhiskerChart we need a new function BOXWHISKERIECDAVE \
for drawing the box *)
IQR[x_] := First[Quantile[x, {3/4}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}] - 
  Quantile[x, {1/4}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}]]
MinIQR[x_] := First@Select[Sort[x], # >= Median[x] - IQR[x]*3/2 &, 1];
MaxIQR[x_] := 
  First@Select[Sort[x, Greater], # <= Median[x] + IQR[x]*3/2 &, 1];
BOXWHISKERIECDAVE[x_] := 
  Flatten[{MinIQR[x], QUANTILEIECDAVE[x, {1/4, 2/4, 3/4}], MaxIQR[x]}];

(* For the BoxWhiskerChart we need to find out the outliers with 3/2 \
boundries around IQR *)
OUTLIERS[l_] := 
  Module[{n = MinIQR[l], m = MaxIQR[l]}, 
   l /. x_ /; (n <= x <= m) -> None];

(* We have a function BOXWHISKERLABEL to overwrite the standard \
tooltip with our new values *)
BOXWHISKERLABEL[data_, index_, label_] := 
  Grid[{{Style["max", Bold], #1[[5]]}, {Style["75%", 
        Bold], #1[[4]]}, {Style["median", Bold], #1[[3]]}, {Style[
        "25%", Bold], #1[[2]]}, {Style["min", Bold], #1[[1]]}}, 
     Dividers -> {{#, #}, {#, #}} &@{Directive[GrayLevel[0.3]], 
       Directive[GrayLevel[0.3]]}, 
     Alignment -> {{Center, ".", {Left}}}, Frame -> GrayLevel[0], 
     BaseStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashing[{}]]] &@
   BOXWHISKERIECDAVE[data];

(* Start drawing our new BoxWhiskerChart with outliers *)
t = List[{4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 1}, {3, 4, 6, 4, 8, 9, 
    2, 7, 10, 7, 5, 6, 5}, Range[1, 10]];
ol = OUTLIERS /@ t;
Show[BoxWhiskerChart[t, ChartLabels -> {"t1", "t2", "t3"},
  Method -> "BoxRange" -> (BOXWHISKERIECDAVE[#] &),
  GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 10, 1]},
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[BOXWHISKERLABEL[##], Tooltip] &),
  ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[2005, 2009], None]],
 ListPlot[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, ol, {2}]]]
```

[image]

Findings:

1. Changing the `Method -> "BoxRange"` does not work with `Outliers` style of `BoxWhiskerChart` anymore so I've to use the `Show` function to overlay the outliers myself
2. The tooltip does not accept the new values returned by the function defined with `Method -> "BoxRange"` so I've had to change that too

Comment: This seems an interesting piece of work, but I don't see how it is a question for this site. Perhaps you could rephrase part of it as a question and then post the rest as a self-question?